# A problem occurred configuring root project 'file_picker'. SDK location not found

Tags: flutter

Ive been trying to use file_picker package in flutter after downgrading, it runs fine on emulator but whenever i try to build apk or run on a real device it throws this error.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'file_picker'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

I have tried adding the local.properties file and adding ANDROID_HOME variable but still same error

Answer (score 0):

go to your **environment variables**
press your windows button if you are in windows and search for environment variables
then add new environment variable named **ANDROID_HOME** that point to you **SDK location** and try again

[image]